# Store and return REST response from kafka

Tags: java, rest, apache-kafka

I have a REST api written in java and want to avoid any extra queries to the database or other external services by using kafka. 
So if the client app sends a request to /some/service, I would check if there is a topic named "/some/service" and also if there is already a log in the topic that corresponds to a previous response from this service to the current user in the last 24 hours, otherwise I'd just execute the service and store the value to be returned in the topic.

Is this use of kafka correct? And, I know kafka is fast but is there a way to identify which of all the responses stored in a topic belongs to the current user without checking every log?

Comment: Well, topic names can't contain slashes... You might want to look at Kafka Streams KTable options, which essentially allows you to create an embedded key-value database (hash table) with all the latest or windowed information from a topic (user ID being the key of the database)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the use case for kafka .Kafka is stream based plateform.

Scenario :- If we send the request metadata and data as json value in the request topic because topic name can not have forward slash , process and put it back in response topic along with metadata to map it to the waiting request. This qualifies for kafka.

But your case is little different, you want to use kafka as cache for 24 hrs, I think it would be better to use distributed cache like redis for this purpose.

Drawback :- Data will increase in kafka over the day so each request will have to scroll all kafka messages in topic to validate the previous request within 24 hrs which is huge performance drawback.